# Clarification: Bernoulli random variable with uniform distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Let $Z$ be a random variable which takes the value 1 when $U \le \frac 14$, $0$ otherwise, where $U$ ~ $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$.

So $Z$ is a Bernoulli random variable with PMF $$p_Z(z) =
\begin{cases}
p,  & \text{if $Z=1$} \\[2ex]
1-p, & \text{if $Z=0$}
\end{cases}$$
Is $p =\frac 14$?

Comment: What is the probability that $U \leq 1/4$?

Comment: Is it $\frac 14$?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You should write the pmf of $Z$ with the probabilities in the 'if' condition.

Comment: So $p_Z(z)=\frac 14, \text{if } U \le \frac 14$

Answer (score 1):

**YES**. Since $Z=1$ if and only if $U \le 1/4$ (and otherwise zero), we get 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}  
   \P(Z=z)=\begin{cases} 1/4 &, \text{if $z=1$} \\
                         3/4 &, \text{if $z=0$} \\
                          0 &, \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$